# Energy storage optimisation pyomo constraints

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm building an optimisation model for arbitrage of a battery storage system, however the energy balance (state of charge of the battery) constraint is not, restricting the charge, I'm new to pyomo so I would really appreciate some help setting the energy balance constraint. Thanks!

I've tried setting the energy balance model.e[i] so that when the battery charges with model.poscharge[i] the value of model.e[i] increases and you can't dishcarge model.negcharge[i] unless you have, in previous iterations, charged through model.poscharge[i], I've tried setting it as a parameter as well but that didn't seem to work.

```
dataset_test = pd.read_csv('TIMEinput_RFR5000 results.csv') # Reading the dataset of prices
DAM_price = dataset_test.iloc[0:24, 2].values # Creating the price Vector

model = ConcreteModel()
model.IDX = RangeSet(24)
model.IDX.pprint()
eff = 0.90

# Variables

model.negcharge = Var(model.IDX, bounds = (0.00, 10.00))
model.poscharge = Var(model.IDX, bounds = (0.00, 10.00))
model.e = Var(model.IDX, bounds = (0.00, 40.00))

# Objective

model.obj =  Objective(expr = sum( -(DAM_price[i-1] * (model.negcharge[i] - model.poscharge[i])) for i in model.IDX))

# Constraints

model.cap1 = Constraint(expr = sum(model.negcharge[i] for i in model.IDX) <= 40)
model.cap2 = Constraint(expr = sum(model.poscharge[i] for i in model.IDX) <= 40)

def ebalance_rule(model, i):
    if i == 1:
        return e[i] == 0
    else:
        return e[i] == e[i-1] + eff*model.poscharge[i] - model.negcharge[i]/eff
model.ebalance = Constraint(model.IDX) 

# Solving the model

opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
results  = opt.solve(model)

results.write()

model.obj.value()

for x in range(1,25):
    print(model.negcharge[x].value)

for x in range(1,25):
    print(model.poscharge[x].value)

for x in range(1,25):
    print(model.e[x].value)
```

What I'm expecting are the values of the state of charge of the battery, however I only get the following:

```
for x in range(1,25):
    print(model.e[x].value)
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm also quite new to using pyomo so this might be a stupid comment/question but I'm not sure you are actually adding your constraint to the model. You define `ebalance_rule` with the required logic but you then never make another reference to this?

Comment: I think @kabdulla is right, you never specified `ebalance_rule` as the rule in your `model.ebalance` constraint. I would also suggest printing the solver output by adding `tee=True` to your call to `solve`. The solver output will tell you the size of the model it received which might have helped with debugging this.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! That was definitely the issue @kabdulla

Comment: Thanks! @BethanyNicholson really appreciate the debugging tip.

Comment: @millanchn I am working on the same problem. I am, however, trying to maximise the NPV figure, not the profit, and think that I need, as you have a positive_charge aswell as negative_charge variables. However, sligthly adapting your code yields a solution which only one charging and discharging event. Did you get a similar issue?